# Why is Persistent Container returning nil?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have set up CoreData stack in my app, but the reference to NSPersistentContainer is returning nil in the PassWordTableVC.

**App Delegate**

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    print("AppDelegate: Application didFinishLaunching")

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if let rootVC = window?.rootViewController as? PassWordTableVC{
            rootVC.container = persistentContainer
    }

    return true
}



lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "PasswordModel")
    container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
        if let error = error {
            
            fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()
```

**PassWordTableVC**

```
var container: NSPersistentContainer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    guard container != nil else{
        fatalError("This view needs a persistent container")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are using Storyboard I guess, and the `viewDidLoad()` might be called before. Instead, I'd make a singleton for your PersistentContainer (in a different class/struct), and access it in `PassWordTableVC`.

Answer (score 0):

`PassWordTableVC viewDidLoad` is likely called before your code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. One simple solution is to add a `didSet` observer to your `container` property:

```swift
var container: NSPersistentContainer! {
    didSet {
        // do what you currently have in viewDidLoad that needs the container
    }
}
```